# React native, Search filter not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of cases rendering in flatlist and I implemented a search function for that. The problem I'm facing is that when user typed wrong word like user want to type 'Acute' but he type 'Acuti' by mistake. When user remove i from Acuti it should re render the flatlist but it's returning empty list same case happen when user remove i from Acuti and type e like Acute from Acuti. I can't figure out what's the problem.

This is my code for search

```
 const searchCases = e => {
    console.log('Text', e);
    let text = e.toLowerCase();
    let filteredName = caseArray.filter(item => {
      return item.name[0].name.toLowerCase().match(text);
    });
    if (!text || text === '') {
      updateState({caseArray: listCase});
    } else if (Array.isArray(filteredName)) {
      updateState({caseArray: filteredName});
    }
  };
```

and this is my flatlist

```
 <FlatList
        data={caseArray}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
        ListEmptyComponent={() => (
          <Text
            style={{
              ...commonStyles.fontBold24,
              color: colors.blackOpacity40,
              textAlign: 'center',
              marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(100),
            }}>
            {strings.NO_DATA_FOUND}
          </Text>
        )}
        renderItem={renderCase}
      />
```

anyone can please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you are always searching on actual data, not the filtered one

e.g.
You have array "x" that you've passed to FlatList and you want to search.
Make sure you copy that data to another state or variable before performing any operation. Because if you haven't copy that data somewhere else you won't get the actual array back when you are canceling the search.

```
const searchCases = e => {
console.log('Text', e);
let text = e.toLowerCase();
let filteredName = copyCaseArray.filter(item => { // copy of caseArray
  return item.name[0].name.toLowerCase().match(text);
});
if (!text || text === '') {
  updateState({caseArray: listCase});
} else if (Array.isArray(filteredName)) {
  updateState({caseArray: filteredName});
}
};
```